# Issue adding Coinbase Exchange API Library to Eclipse Project

Tags: java, eclipse, api, libraries, coinbase-api

I'm trying to add the Coinbase Exchange Java API to my eclipse project.

The zip API file has the following file folder setup
`source/main/java/com/coinbase/excahnge/api`

All the source files are in the API folder.  The rest of the folders are empty.

At first I tried to import it as a project but got a error saying 'no project found'.

I did not see any options under import to import the source files into my project.

Any help would be great, could not find any documentation on Coinbase Exchange website on how to use their Java API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Eclipse Import function expects either Eclipse projects, or something that can be converted to Eclipse projects (like Maven .pom files etc.).

All you have is a zip file containing some .java files.

Just place these .java files in your project folder, under `com/coinbase/exchange/api`.